# Alterar tema do primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando alterar o tema do primefaces, baixei todos os temas disponíveis usando o maven e meu arquivo web.xml ficou assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>evolutionary</display-name>
    <display-name>evolutionary</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>blitzer</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

A estrutura da minha app está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho 2 arquivos web.xml no projeto: 1 fica dentro de WebContent/WEB-INF. O outro fica em src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. O que está configurado é o segundo. Isso pode influenciar?

Comment: Se seu projeto é maven, você não precisa da pasta WebContent. Sim, em  um projeto maven o web.xml que vai para a aplicação é o que está dentro da pasta webapp/WEB-INF

Answer (score 1):

Creio que sim, mas no entanto para mim funcionou assim:

O tema deve ser alterado no `web.xml` como você já fez mas no diretório `WebContent/WEB-INF`,
 e você deve ter também colocar os temas baixados do *PrimeFaces* no diretório

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
```